# See if value exists in any column of every row in PostgresQL

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

Imagining I have this table, I want to be able to find the brands that exist associated with every id.
Note that this is not equivalent to finding if the value exists for every row, since a single id may exist several times.
The result I would expect in this case would be Mercedes-Benz.

```
 id |    brand1     |    brand2     |    brand3
----+---------------+---------------+---------------
  1 | Mercedes-Benz |               | Fiat
  2 | Honda         |               | Mercedes-Benz
  3 | Audi          |               | Audi
  3 | Audi          |               | Mercedes-Benz
  4 | Mercedes-Benz |               | Mercedes-Benz
  5 | Mercedes-Benz | Mercedes-Benz |
  5 | Mercedes-Benz | Mercedes-Benz |
  6 | Mercedes-Benz |               | Mercedes-Benz
  7 | Mercedes-Benz | Mercedes-Benz |
  8 | Audi          |               | Audi
  8 | Audi          |               | Mercedes-Benz
```

I have tried using `EXIST`, but I haven't been able to find an elegant "postgresql" way to iterate in the id columns.

### Result:

```
  |    brand      |  
  +---------------+
  | Mercedes-Benz |
```

Comment: Odd table design. Why 3 brand columns? I'd have only one, and more rows instead.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @jarlh

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, having that table data.

Comment: The result I am expecting is just a column named brand, which contains all of the brands that exist associated with every id.  So Audi would be left out, since it does not exist for id 4,5,6,7. Honda would be out since it does not exist for id 1, 2,4,5,6,7,8. Fiat would be out for similar reasons.  As for the table design, this is actually the byproduct of another more complex query. Thank you for your help

Comment: That's _describing_ the result.  Now _specify_ it!

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 [is no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) you should plan an upgrade to the current version as soon as possible.

Comment: Okay, I have edited the question @jarlh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpivot the data -- I recommend using a lateral join -- and then aggregate:

```
select v.brand
from t cross join lateral
     (values (t.brand1), (t.brand2), (t.brand3)) v(brand)
group by brand
having count(distinct t.id) = (select count(distinct t.id) from t);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize the data (if possible, change the table structure, otherwise you can run a query to build it on the fly)

```
SELECT id, brand1 AS brand FROM table
UNION
SELECT id, brand2 FROM table
UNION
SELECT id, brand3 FROM table
```

From there, you can use standard aggregation functions to find the information you need : GROUP BY brand, and COUNT the number of ID

Comment: This also seems to work. Which one is more efficient, this one or the one using cross join?

Comment: I am not familiar with lateral joins to judge with certainty, but instinctively a keyword should be more efficient than a query that try to mimic it, so the solution of Gordon Linoff should be better.